# Changing SSH keys on the compute node in pcluster using slurm

Tags: slurm

Our login-node is currently one of the compute node, residing in a separate queue. We want to setup custom SSH keys on /etc/ssh for that login-node.

We tried pulling in the custom SSH keys on the post-install script, which does the job, but for some reason slurm stops working.
When we try to submit a job, it says,
`sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Invalid account or account/partition combination specified.`

This error goes away, when I restart slurm, `systemctl restart slurmctld.service` on the head node manually after everything is built.

The root user is still able to submit jobs

We want to do this, so that our users can ssh in the node via our domain name, and it doesn't complain about changing ecdsa keys whenever we rebuild our cluster so we want to maintain the same set of keys.

So what is the best way to setup custom SSH keys on the login-node?

`/var/log/slurmd.log`

```
[2023-06-13T04:01:28.145] error: Node configuration differs from hardware: CPUs=2:2(hw) Boards=1:1(hw) SocketsPerBoard=2:1(hw) CoresPerSocket=1:1(hw) ThreadsPerCore=1:2(hw)
[2023-06-13T04:01:28.604] CPU frequency setting not configured for this node
[2023-06-13T04:01:29.003] slurmd version 23.02.2 started
[2023-06-13T04:01:29.844] slurmd started on Tue, 13 Jun 2023 04:01:29 -0400
[2023-06-13T04:01:29.844] CPUs=2 Boards=1 Sockets=2 Cores=1 Threads=1 Memory=3850 TmpDisk=71667 Uptime=324 CPUSpecList=(null) FeaturesAvail=(null) FeaturesActive=(null)
```

Have tested on repeated attempts and found this code introduction to be the issue, because it looks seemingly unrelated at first.